# how to create element in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am creating a element by using native javascript in angular js but i want to create it in angular js not by native js .Please help me to resolve this snippet.

```
 var navigateOffpage = function navigateOffpage(tab) {

      // TODO: use angular.element instead of document.createElement
     var link = document.createElement("a");   

      link.href = tab.visibleLocation;   

      link.target = "_self";

      // TODO: use angular.element() to create and inject dom elements.
       document.body.appendChild(link);

     link.click();

    };
```

Comment: **[angular.element()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)** is subset of jQuery methods or if jQuery.js included in page before angular.js it is jQuery.

Comment: how can I change document.createelement("a") to angular,element(a)  and  document.body.appendChild(link) to angular.element.append (link)

Comment: Same way you would using jQuery API. There is no way you read the docs I linked to thoroughly in the few minutes since I provided link to them....  start with `angular.element('<a>')`

Comment: Nothing is `urgent` here. Don't ever mention that on this site. There is nothing wrong with using native methods ... all that libraries and frameworks do is wrap those in the first place.

Comment: sorry to mention that...but i have requirement of changing this native code to angular as a code up gradation process. Please suggest any ways to achieve same.

Comment: Not sure why you would even need to do this in the first place. Why aren't you using angular templating and data model to drive what gets displayed in view? Can make a directive out of this and pass in data array